# Windows Phone Setting Visibility after an animation has executed

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I have a View and  View Model. The View Model has a bool on there (Foo.CanSelect) that on change will set off a data trigger in the View.

This applies some funky fade out animation, and sets the visibility to collapsed in the final key frame. This is all well and good for the current session, but when I bring the app out from a tombstoning event (de-serialize it) the view is Visible again.

Foo.CanSelect is the correct value but it isn’t bound to the Visibility, because if it was, when the property is changed the visible state is immediately collapsed.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could persist the value of `Foo.CanSelect` when the application is tombstoned, and then read it on restore and update the visibility of the element accordingly. It may be easier to use visual states instead and simply store the required state on tombstoning and restore that state on resume.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll have a look into visual states. For the moment i solved it by adding another bool called IsVisible which is bound to visibility, i set the CanSelect which tiggers the animation then set the IsVisible straight after which seems to be persisting.